# SQLAlchemy: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm a new learner on Python and SQLAlchemy, and I met a curious problem as below.

```
user = Table('users', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

then I

```
print(user.columns)
```

it works fine, the output are user.ID, user.Name, etc. But then:

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

session.query(user).order_by(user.id)
```

shows error:

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I change the "id" to "Name", it's the same error.
I also tried the `filter_by` method, the same error.

Why this happened?

Comment: I figure it out. I miss the mapper process.

Comment: What does "I miss the mapper process" mean.

Answer (score 33):

You could use:

```
session.query(user).order_by(user.c.id)
```

Comment: To be clear, "c" was missing in the attribute name and must be used "user.c.id"

Comment: What is c there stand for?

Comment: I'd guess for "columns"

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the top answer when you search for this error, I will drop my solution for this as well here.

For my problem, I had to reference the `class` instead of the `table` in my models `remote_side`

so it had to be `"Transaction.id"` instead of `transactions.id`

```
class Transaction(Base):
    __tablename__ = "transactions"
    ...
    
    offset_transaction = relationship(
        ...
        remote_side="Transaction.id",
    )
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`users` is a Table, not an ORM model. ORM model columns are referenced directly, for example `User.id`, but Table columns are referenced through the intermediate `columns` attribute, or more commonly, its alias `c`: `users.c.id`.

When the OP comments that they "miss the mapper process", they mean that they intended to create an ORM model by mapping the table to a Python class, but did not do so. In SQLAlchemy's declarative syntax the mapping happens implicitly, but it can be done explicitly. This explicit process is known as classical mapping, and looks like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

# Create a registry to hold mapper details.
mapper_registry = orm.registry()

# Define a table.
users = sa.Table(
    'users',
     mapper_registry.metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String)
)

# Declare a class that will become an ORM model.
class User:
    pass

# Map the class to the table. This adds attributes 
# such as id and name to the 
# User class.
mapper_registry.map_imperatively(User, users)

# Create the table in the database.
engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')
mapper_registry.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many things have changed, so here is a solution that works now using `select` instead of `query`.

Sorry for the different table and column names, but this was from an actual query.

Using MSSQL database with ODCB driver:

```
from sqlalchemy import select, create_engine, MetaData, Table, URL
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

connect_url = URL.create(
    'mssql+pyodbc',
    host =      'server',
    port =      'port',
    database =  'database',
    query =     dict(driver = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'))

engine = create_engine(connect_url)
connection = engine.connect()
metadata = MetaData()
reqgroups = Table('ReqGroup', metadata, autoload_with=engine)

# Print the column names. This works and shows REQGROUPID as one of the columns
print(reqgroups.columns.keys())

with Session(engine) as session:
    
    # Filter with columns REQGROUPID
    stmt = select(reqgroups).filter_by(REQGROUPID = "Tarve_ts")
    ResultSet = session.execute(stmt).fetchone()

    print(ResultSet)
```